# jwplayer - change controls look when caption is on

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

i'm building my own jwplayer skin (jwplayer 6) using xml file and i changed the look of the controls bar.
when the caption is on i want the controls bar to look different.
Is that possible?

I found this:

```
    events: {
            onCaptionsChange: function(event) {          
             }
   }
```

and i think i can add a class to the control bar and work with it with css but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: What do you want the controlbar to change to when the captions are on?

Comment: when the captions are on i want the control bar to change his color and his position (change the margin)

Comment: Ah. I'm afraid once the player has been set up, you really can't move elements around. The only thing I could think of here is using some CSS (through js) to move the controlbar position when the captions change, but this would only apply to HTML5 mode, not Flash mode.